# How to setup a root domain redirect for https with google domains

Tags: heroku, dns, google-domain-api

Using Google Domains, I've set up a synthetic record to redirect foo.com -> www.foo.com.  Just like in this example:

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6346300?hl=en

However, it doesn't seem to work with https://foo.com.

How do I configure it so that the subdomain forward works with https as well?

To give it more context, I'm mapping my custom domain to a heroku app, so I've set up a CNAME record for www.foo.com, and would like https://foo.com to be mapped to https://www.foo.com

Comment: I just ran into this too. Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: Whoever is interested, this answer seams to explain it all: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85519/can-i-configure-google-domains-to-redirect-a-bare-domain-to-a-subdomain-over-htt

Answer (score 0):

Before providing any input please confirm if you are using any pointing service?

If http://foo.com is working whereas https://foo.com is not then you may need any service like pointDNS or cloudflare.